# Android GCM: Problems storing registrationIDs on Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, google-cloud-messaging

Google's GCM servers will issue one GCM registrationId per application/device pair. So if a certain user has your application on two devices each device will have its own registrationId.

The problem I am facing is that I store those registrationIds on a table with two columns:

```
+---------+-----------+
|userId   |userGCMId  +
+---------+-----------+
```

where userId is the Id of the user on my application, which is the same regardless of the device he is using, and userGCMId is the registrationId issued by Google.

If I make userId the primary key of this table I won't be able to store the userGCMId of the user if he installs my app on a second device, since the userId/primary key would be the same for both (and thus this second device won't receive my push notifications).

I thought about making the primary key composite using both columns, but the GCM registrationId can be as large as 4k (according to a Google engineer), so in theory it could be as long as 4,000 chars, and this is too big for a primary key.

**Solutions I am considering:**

1. Since in practice most GMC registrationIds are 512 chars or shorter I figured I could make that column a varchar(512) and use it as part of the primary key.
2. Another option is to keep the userGCMid column as text, and add a third column, the device where the id is coming from, and make the primary key(userId,device).

Did any of you solve this in the past? Any ideas on the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using option 2, and it seems to be working fine.

You might also wanna use the MAC address of the device instead of its model, as this will allow the user to install the app on two devices of the same model and receive push notifications on both.